# Display part of an Image, inside a Frame, in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: image, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, crop

In Xamarin.Forms, how can I display only a specific part of a larger Image (i.e. crop the Image), inside a Frame?

Lets say that I e.g. want to display the right lower quadrant, like this:

Image:
[image: Strandsnäckan Glass & Café]

Frame:
[image: Frame]

The part I want (e.g. right lower quadrant):
[image: Strandsnäckan & Frame]

To Display (the Frame with part of the Image inside):
[image: Strandsnäckan Right Lower Quadrant]

My Code (the double Frames are just for thicker borders):

```
<Frame BorderColor="#880014" BackgroundColor="#880014" Padding="4">
    <Frame BorderColor="#880014" BackgroundColor="#FFFFFF" Padding="0">
        <!--
        An Image something like this...
        <Image Source="{local:ImageResource SGC.Resources.SGCLogo.png}" Aspect="Fill" ... />
        -->
    </Frame>
</Frame>
```

Comment: Did you want to show the full image with the frame or just the frame ? If you want to show only that specific portion of the image i suggest to cut the image with some tool (photoshop or illustrator) and simply place it on the frame. But if you want to display the frame over the image just use a grid, place the image first and then the frame

Comment: @OlaStrom If you want to crop image and get part of image, displaying image, I suggest you can use **Xam.Plugins.ImageCropper** to do this.

Comment: @FabriBertani Yes, everybody knows that you could always use Photoshop or a similar program to fix this, but that was not my question since it would get kind of messy if I need e.g. 64 different parts of the same image. Then one image and 64 different xaml codes to crop it would make more sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is to use an [`<AbsoluteLayout>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/absolute-layout) with Proportional values inside the `<Frame>`.

```
<AbsoluteLayout>
    <Image Source="{local:ImageResource SGC.Resources.SGCLogo.png}"  
                   AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="1, 1, 2, 2"  
                   AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"  
                   Aspect="Fill"/>  
</AbsoluteLayout>
```

Set the *LayoutFlags* to treat all values as Proportional:
`AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"`.

And use *LayoutBounds* to set Proportional values for "X, Y, Width, Height" i.e.: 
(`AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="1, 1, 2, 2"`)

Where "1, 1..." is the right lower quadrant.
*(use "0, 1..." for left lower quadrant)*:

[image]

And "...2, 2" crops the Image to 1/4 of its size (two columns and two rows).
*(use "...8, 8" for 1/64 Image size or "...2, 4" for 1/8 size like this)*:

[image]